# Laravel Jetstream (Livewire) not returning user through eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to return the user name who submitted an article, but unable to access this via an eloquent relationship.

Models/Thing

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

with user_id stored in the `things` table

However this dump isn't returning user data:  `dd($this->thing->users->name);`

Error:

```
Attempt to read property "name" on null
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
```

in my view you are using users with belongTo. it will work if you will use.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class );

}
```

and then

```
dd( $this->thing->user->name );
```